# Material-UI ripple/hover effect carrying over to newly mounted component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am experiencing an issue with Material-UI's ripple effect when mounting/un-mounting button components. I have some buttons which toggle state, and the button which is displayed is based on this state. The problem is that when I click the button to toggle this state, and the new button is rendered, the ripple/hover effects that were applied from the previous button carries over to the newly mounted button.

[image]

Here is a simplified example of this issue on [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tbutman/material-ui-ripple/tree/master/?file=/src/demo.js).

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to prevent this behavior?

Comment: If it happens even when the button is a child of a totally different type of element, then please provide a code sandbox that reproduces that case.

Comment: @RyanCogswell going to edit my question as I was not able to reproduce that behavior. Originally, I thought I noticed the same behavior when wrapping the components in a div/span, but it looks like I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

React (and thus Material-UI) thinks they are the same button with changed props. You can make React realize they are different buttons by giving them distinct keys (e.g. "button1" and "button2" in my altered version of your sandbox): https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-fermat-q9ojt?file=/src/demo.js.

```
export function SingleButtonExample() {
  const classes = useStyles2();
  const [displayedButton, setDisplayedButton] = useState(1);
  const toggleDisplayedButton = () =>
    setDisplayedButton(displayedButton === 1 ? 2 : 1);

  const button1 = (
    <Button
      key="button1"
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      onClick={toggleDisplayedButton}
    >
      Show Button 2
    </Button>
  );

  const button2 = (
    <Button
      key="button2"
      variant="contained"
      color="secondary"
      onClick={toggleDisplayedButton}
    >
      Show Button 1
    </Button>
  );

  return (
    <div className={displayedButton === 1 ? classes.button1 : classes.button2}>
      {displayedButton === 1 ? button1 : button2}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another way to handle this (which may be more convenient in some cases) is just to make sure the two buttons have a different spot in the JSX:

```
 return (
    <div className={displayedButton === 1 ? classes.button1 : classes.button2}>
      {displayedButton === 1 && button1}
      {displayedButton !== 1 && button2}
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Edit compassionate-khorana-4e5cl]

This will become either `<div>{false}<Button/></div>` or `<div><Button/>{false}</div>` which still allows React to tell that they are different buttons.

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan Cogswell! Thought I had tried adding keys to my components before but apparently that is what I missed. Looks like I mistakenly added id attributes. Good to remember this in these situations though, as the use of keys has only become a matter of habit for me when working with arrays (which React will warn you about).

Comment: @tbutman I added a second alternative that avoids needing to add keys which may be more convenient in some situations.

Comment: that is an interesting solution. The implications of that never crossed my mind. All this time I have been treating those two versions as equivalent in my mental model; however, that makes it clear that splitting it into two lines is not the same, even if one of the lines will always resolve to null. Is that because you will always have two components in the second variation - one null and one defined?

Comment: Each JSX node gets translated into a `React.createElement` call by Babel. The child nodes of an element are basically an array of objects (from `createElement`) in the parent object. Even an `{expression}` element that evaluates to null or false still is represented by an object in that array of the parent's children. In the absence of keys it will assume that an element is "the same" if it is in the same position and has the same type. With keys, the position no longer needs to be the same, but the key does. Giving the two buttons the same key will retain the issue even in this last syntax.